# Display API data with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I fetch the api correctly with all data, but I can't display
If I put items by default, it displays them, however the items retrieved from the API are not displayed
I tried to move the api fetch directly into ActivitiePage but nothing changes

Item.vue:

```
  <div class="item-container">
    <img :src="item.Image" alt="Item Image" class="item-image">
    <div class="item-details">
      <div class="item-text">{{ item.Text }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  },
  props: {
    item: Object,
  },
}
</script>
```

ActivitiePage:

```
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
        <option v-for="time in itemTimes" :key="time">{{ time }}</option>
      </select>
      <item v-for="item in items" :key="item.Text" :item="item" @share="onShareButtonClick" />
    </ul>
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-else>
      <div v-if="items.length === 0">No items available.</div>
      <div v-else>
        <div>Items:</div>
        <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(items, null, 2) }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from '@/components/Item.vue';
import SearchBar from '@/components/SearchBar.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Item,
  },
  created() {
    fetch('/api/v1/Activities/all')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Network response was not ok, status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.items = data; // Assign the data directly to items
        this.loading = false;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error retrieving items:', error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a variable set for `items`. You need to add a function `data` in the `export default`, which returns an Object that has the data:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            loading: false
        }
    }
}
```

Check the link below for the Vue docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: I alreaday added this, I just dont display it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).